# Convert a DateTime Object to Datetime String so i can insert data to sqflite

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am building a To-do app where a user will have to schedule a task to be performed in a particular day and time.

I have been able to build my Date and Time picker following a tutorial I saw online, but now I am trying to save the selected-date-and-time to SQL using the flutter SQflite, I read that for now we can't save a DateTime object to the database directly except it's been converted to String or Int.

Now I am having issues converting it... maybe because I don't know how it's done, I keep getting the error

> A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'DateTime'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'DateTime'.

I was able to format the Selected Date and Time using the Intl package... check the image to see how its been formatted [image]

This are my codes bellow ... selectedDayAndTime is the DateTime object that i want to change to string

```
import './model.dart';

class TodoItem extends Model {
  static String table = 'todo_items';

  int id;
  String title;
  String description;
  String date;
  bool complete;

  TodoItem({this.id, this.title, this.description, this.date, this.complete});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      'title': title,
      'description': description,
      'date': date,
      'complete': complete,
    };

    if (id != null) {
      map['id'] = id;
    }
    return map;
  }

  static TodoItem fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return TodoItem(
        id: map['id'],
        title: map['title'],
        description: map['description'],
        date: map['date'],
        complete: map['complete'] == 1);
  }
}
```

Then my DB codes

```
import 'dart:async';
import '../models/model.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

abstract class DB {
  static Database _db;

  static int get _version => 3;

  static Future<void> init() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      String _path = await getDatabasesPath() + 'example';
      _db = await openDatabase(_path, version: _version, onCreate: onCreate);
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex);
    }
  }

  static void onCreate(Database db, int version) async => await db.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE todo_items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, title STRING NOT NULL, description STRING, date TEXT, complete BOOLEAN)');


  static Future<int> insert(String table, Model model) async =>
      await _db.insert(table, model.toMap());
}
```

Then On my Main.dart file

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // String _task;
  String titleInput;
  String descriptionInput;
  DateTime selectedDateAndTime;

  List<TodoItem> _tasks = [];
Future _selectDayAndTimeL(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime _selectedDay = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2021),
        lastDate: DateTime(2030),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) => child);

    TimeOfDay _selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
    );

    if (_selectedDay != null && _selectedTime != null) {
      //a little check
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedDateAndTime = DateTime(
        _selectedDay.year,
        _selectedDay.month,
        _selectedDay.day,
        _selectedTime.hour,
        _selectedTime.minute,
      );
      // _selectedDate = _selectedDay;
    });
    // print('...');
  }

// This is the Save function
void _save() async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
    TodoItem item = TodoItem(
        title: titleInput,
        description: descriptionInput,
        date: selectedDateAndTime,
        complete: false);

    await DB.insert(TodoItem.table, item);
    setState(() {
      titleInput = '';
      descriptionInput = '';
      selectedDateAndTime = ''; // I tried this but kept getting that same error
    });
    refresh();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert and revert the DateTime in 2 methods, in order to save them to database:

1. Convert to Formatted string:

```dart
void main() {
  var dt = new DateTime.now();
  var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  String formatted = formatter.format(dt); // Save this to DB
  print(formatted); // Output: 2021-05-11 08:52:45
  print(formatter.parse(formatted)); // Convert back to DateTime object
}
```

2. Convert to UNIX time:

```dart
void main() {
  final dt = DateTime.now();
  final dtInEpoch = dt.millisecondsSinceEpoch; // Save this to DB
  print(dtInEpoch); // Output: 1620697965915
  print(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(dtInEpoch)); // Convert back to DateTime object
}
```

Comment: I tried to get the Dates and time selected to show in the Listtile Subtitle but its not showing... just coming out blank... his is the code i tried using to call it `subtitle: Text(formatted != null ? formatted : 'Default date'),`  also tried calling the Date to see if am calling the wrong function but still giving the same issue  `subtitle: Text(
            item.date != null ? item.date : 'Defualt Date And Time',
          ),'`

Comment: This is how i added the fix you gave `String formatted;
  DateTime selectedDateAndTime;`     `void mainn() {
    var dt = new DateTime.now();
    var formatter = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
    String formatted = formatter.format(dt); // Save this to DB
    print(formatted); // Output: 2021-05-11 08:52:45
    print(formatter.parse(formatted)); // Convert back to DateTime object
  }`